# fail-over connection URL for hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm using Hibernate 4 to connect to Oracle 10g database using Java 1.7

This is a standalone program which has a main method which I'm running daily via batch job.

My hibernate config has below entry for connection URL:

```
  ...
 <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.0.6:1521:tango" />
 <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="nde" />
 <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="nde" />
 ...
```

Now, I've fail-over Oracle server as well. Where can I specify the connection URL for this failover server so that if server at 192.168.0.6:1521 goes down, I can point to this fail-over server?

Thanks